# Custom Block on a Custom Controller Doesn't Render

Tags: magento2, controllers

I have a custom controller which I'm trying to get a block rendered.

> Company/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;


class Index extends Action
{

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
    }
}
```

> Company/Module/Block/Hello.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Hello extends Template
{

}
```

> Company/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="testing_hello" frontName="testing">
            <module name="Company_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> Company/Module/view/frontend/layout/testing_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="custom.name" class="Company\Module\Block\Hello" template="testing.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Company/Module/view/frontend/templates/testing.phtml

```
<h2>Hello World</h2>
```

For some reason I don't see `<h2>Hello World</h2>` I just see blank / empty content area but the rest of the page is loaded correctly.

I'll really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this issue

- either you should changes layout name
- Or Changes the route name

### Explanation:

whenever a page a render that times a handler is will automatically.

That handler is **`{route_id}_{controllerName}_{ActioName}`**

And for every page, ***magento load a layout file automatically that is***

**`{route_id}_{controllerName}_{ActioName}.xml`**

Example,Customer account creation page **customer/account/create** load `customer_account_creata.xml` because of its has a handler `customer_account_creata`.

As you have checked `vendor/magento/module-customer/module-customer/etc/frontend/routes.xml`.

And you will find  `route id` is `customer` .`<route id="customer" frontName="customer">`.

**SO, either you will changes**

> route id="testing_hello"

**to**

> route id="testing"

Or  change layout files name

> testing_index_index.xml

to

> testing_hello_index_index.xml

Comment: Thanks, now I'm getting an another error; "Invalid template file" though.

Comment: Please changes `template="testing.phtml"` to `template="Company/Module::testing.phtml"`   and check .but must insure that you should  flush cache properly

Answer (score 2):

Try replace line in **Company/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml**:

```
<route id="testing_hello" frontName="testing">
```

to:

```
<route id="testing" frontName="testing">
```

Don't forget clean cache after modifications.
Your controller will be available at #your_domain#/testing/index/index